# Returning different status for more KPIs from single Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I'd like to create one KPI dataset which would feed more KPIs at SQL Report Server 2016.

The final part of my Stored Procedure is:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- KPI Result
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT
     CONVERT(varchar(4), @YearId) + '-0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), @MonthId)    AS DateId
    ,@ProductType           AS ProductType  
    ,@ePJs                  AS KPI_CZ_Count_ePJ
    ,@PJs                   AS KPI_CZ_Count_PJ
    ,@Plan_CA_PJ_count      AS KPI_CZ_PLAN_Count_PJ
    ,@PJ_NV                 AS KPI_CZ_NV_PJ
    ,@Plan_NV_Prod_PJ       AS KPI_CZ_NV_Prod_PJ
    ,@PJ_NV / @ePJs         AS KPI_CZ_Avg_NV_PJ
    ,@Plan_Avg_NV_per_PJ    AS KPI_CZ_PLAN_Avg_NV_PJ
    ,i.[Status]             AS KPI_CZ_Performance_Status
FROM
    kpi.Indicator i
WHERE 
    (100.0 * @PJs / @Plan_CA_PJ_count) BETWEEN i.RangeMin AND i.RangeMax
    AND NameID = 10 -- Indicator type
```

Column Status from table kpi.Indicator is for KPI's background colour and looks like:
[image]
I want to have status for all KPI pair, eg. @PJs / @Plan_CA_PJ_count, @PJ_NV / @Plan_NV_Prod_PJ.

How can this be achieved?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @SeanLange What's wrong with my question? KPI status has just 3 states and I need them as show on the picture.

Comment: Well I assume you want some help with the query? I can't really do that because I have nothing to work with. Where does IndicatorID come from? What about NameID, Status, created, modified??? Remember we can't see your screen and have no idea of any details of your project other than what you posted. It is great that you posted what you have tried and the desired output. Those are both important parts of a question. But without something to work with there is nothing anybody can do but guess. Maybe you just need to group by IndicatorID? I don't know.

Comment: You've missed out something pretty critical here - what are the rules for making the value -1/ 0 / 1? You have about seven columns there that could be compared against your range.